# Script for the functionality of Code Sample

Tags: javascript

I just want to have the functionality of Code Sample(this is a button above text format box in SOF when we ask a question) which is also there in StackOverFlow. How to get the color of keywords which are shown in IDE. 
`<pre><code>` works good to show the code but how to display the exact color which IDE is displaying, that is what I don't know. Can we have same functionality in Windows form to display the code.

Comment: i have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this: http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

If you're using jQuery, then: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are asking for a code syntax highlighting tool in  - if so check out

1. http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/
2. http://colorcode.codeplex.com/

You did not specify a language though.

Comment: I am going to use this in windows form in c#,

Comment: @Nils: then the second link will work for you, its a library you can include into your project.

Comment: it is a dll which is good but having no description for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) according to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well

Comment: it works well for web, but was in need of windows application